# Disproving $A-S-S(Angle-Side-Side)$ congruence condition...

Tags: geometry, triangles, congruences-geometry

I know that $A-S-S$$(Angle-Side-Side)$ congruence does not  exist.But I cannot disprove it. Every time I draw a figure,I get two congruent triangles.

**My Attempt**-[image]

So,we draw two lines such that $AB=DE$.Now we draw angles $\angle CAB=\angle FDB.$Now,By compass we take measurements such that $CB=FE.$By Cutting arcs on lines $A$ and $B$ we see that $AC=DF$ always.So,Now the two triangles are congruent by $SAS.$

Someone please help me out of this,with a diagram to disprove it.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a counterexample that should be what you are looking for:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Look at your method but imagine that last side being done by setting the point of compasses, set to the given length, at E and striking an arc.  There are **three** possible results.  In might happen that the arc is simply NOT long enough to reach side AC.  In that case, there is NO such triangle,  It might happen that the arc cuts side AC in two different places.  In that case there are **two** such triangles (this is the case that  aras is giving).  It might happen that the arc strikes side AC in exactly one place.  In that case, side AC is **tangent** to the arc so the triangle is a **right** triangle.

Answer (score 1):

Did you see that your example is a **right** triangle?  Look at your method but imagine that last side being done by setting the point of compasses, set to the given length, at E and striking an arc.  There are **three** possible results.  In might happen that the arc is simply NOT long enough to reach side AC.  In that case, there is NO such triangle,  It might happen that the arc cuts side AC in two different places.  In that case there are **two** such triangles (this is the case that  aras is giving).  It might happen that the arc strikes side AC in exactly one place.  In that case, side AC is **tangent** to the arc so the triangle is a **right** triangle.